# How do i disregard a django filter field if the field is empty?

Tags: django, django-models

So, i started to code a filtering system to my django application. It goes like this

```
class Person(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
     middle_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

i wanted to filter which Person has a field containing x value if other fields are empty, like this algorithm

```
results = Person.objects.filter(first_name__contains = "a")
```

but if other fields are not empty, i want to filter it like this

```
results = Person.objects.filter(first_name__contains = "a", middle_name__contains = "a", last_name__contains = "a")
```

depending on which fields have none empty value.

my first attempt was this:

```
if first_name != "":
     results = Person.objects.filter(first_name__contains = first_name)
if middle_name != "":
     results = results.filter(middle_name__contains = middle_name)
if last_name != "":
     results = results.filter(last_name__contains = last_name)
```

My problem here is that it filters it sequentially, so if i filter the `middle_name` only or `last_name` only, it would return me an error since `results` is not yet defined, could anyone help me with this?

is there an algorithm that goes like this?
`results = Person.objects.filter(first_name__contains = first_name if first_name != "" else JUST REMOVE THIS FILTER)`?
because if it filters a `""` it would return all your data. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build up a queryset in stages

```
qs = Person.objects.all()
if first_name != "":
   qs = qs.filter( first_name__contains=first_name )
if middle_name != "":
   qs = qs.filter( middle_name__contains=middle_name )
if last_name != "":
   qs = qs.filter( last_name__contains=last_name )
```

You can do much the same with [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)  for OR-type matching (it's a bit fiddlier)

```
qs = Person.objects.all()
q = None
for op, name in (( "first_name__contains", first_name),
                 ( "middle_name__contains", middle_name),
                 ( "last_name__contains",  last_name)) :

    if name != "":
        if q:
            q = q | Q( **{ op: name} )
        else
            q =     Q( **{ op: name} )

if q:
    qs = qs.filter(q)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that since you told me, because i started my function with Person.objects.none() because i used it as an ajax to let it know to return none if all fields are empty. Now, my code is like this.

`results = Person.objects.none()`
`if first_name != "" and middle_name != "" and last_name != "":`
`     results = Person.objects.all()`
`     if first_name != "":`
`          results = results.filter(first_name__contains = first_name)`
`     ...`

Comment: what i meant was `if first_name != "" or middle_name != "" or last_name != ""`

Comment: An easy mistake. I always prefer `if any([ first_name != "", ...,  last_name != ""]) :` or `if all([...])` where appropriate. Also it's Pythonic to rely on null strings being falsy values: `if any([ first_name, middle_name, last_name ]) :`

Comment: I was going to add, watch out for spaces being Truthy and use `.strip()`, bur filtering on a space in a last name is perfectly sensible if you vaguely remember "Someone de la Something".

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, you want to do an `OR`ing between `first_name`, `last_name`, and `middle_name`, when querying for a specific provided string.

I highly recommend you using [Q Object Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) in Django

your code will be simpler like the following:

```
text = 'a'
results = Person.objects.filter(Q(first_name__contains=text) | Q(middle_name__contains=text) | Q(last_name__contains=text))
```

Comment: Author mentioned this: `if other fields are empty, like this algorithm` and in your example it's only selecting records with `OR` operator.

Comment: Radwan is right, but still, thank you in the comment, I am currently looking on Q Object Lookups. thank you so much.